# Abstract class instantiate its own concrete class

Tags: java, design-patterns, olingo

I came across this while I was reading the Apache Olingo v4 source code. Is this a known pattern to instantiate the concrete class.

What is the advantage or purpose of separating abstract class Odata and concert class ODataImpl when they are bound together in the newInstance() method.

```
public abstract class OData {

  private static final String IMPLEMENTATION = "org.apache.olingo.server.core.ODataImpl";

  public static OData newInstance() {
    try {
      final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(OData.IMPLEMENTATION);

      /*
       * We explicitly do not use the singleton pattern to keep the server state free
       * and avoid class loading issues also during hot deployment.
       */
      final Object object = clazz.newInstance();

      return (OData) object;

    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new ODataRuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can compile this code without having the concrete class.  Maybe the absence of the ODataImpl is a valid state.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's easy to change the path to the implementation (one string). Eventually, this string could be stored in preferences later. I've seen this kind of code in an implementation of Simple Factory (aka ConcreteFactory), but usually the implementation is passed as an arg to the function.